# Logstash can't connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash

I'm trying to synchronize the data between the MySQL database and an Elasticsearch using logstash.
For that, I created a `docker-compose` file that creates containers for Elasticsearch, MySQL and Logstash.

here is the file:

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
   elasticsearch:
     image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.1.1
     container_name: pelasticsearch
     environment:
     - discovery.type=single-node
     - cluster.name=docker-cluster
     - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
     - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
     ulimits:
       memlock:
         soft: -1
         hard: -1
     volumes:
     - elasticsearch:/home/django/elasticsearch
     ports:
     - 9200:9200

   db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: pmysqldb
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/pdata/data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ecommerce

   adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

   logstash:
       image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.1.1
       links:
       - elasticsearch
       volumes:
       - ${PWD}/ls_config:/usr/share/logstash/config/
       command: bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jdbc
       command: logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf
       depends_on:
       - elasticsearch

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

I also had the `logstash.yml` and the `logstash.conf` files to configure my logstash plugin.

### logstash.conf

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "./mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecommerce"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "exmaple"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * from ecommerce.table;"
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
        user => elastic
        password => changeme
   }
}
```

### logstash.yml

```
---
http.host: '0.0.0.0'
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: [ "elasticsearch:9200"]
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: elastic
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: changeme
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
```

So, when I run a `docker-compose up` all my containers are running including logstash, however when the logstash tries to run the conf file it seems to be unable to load the driver and returns an error as the following:

```
logstash_1       |   2056     LogStash::ConfigurationError
logstash_1       |   2056     com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?
logstash_1       |   2056       /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:163:in `open_jdbc_connection'
```

Since I'm new to both docker and logstash, is there anything I'm doing wrong? and how to solve this error.

Comment: which platform you are using?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'platform'?

Comment: windows/Linux platform

Comment: I'm using an Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: so, where did you place your jar file in the root directory?

Comment: Just add absolute path there

Comment: the jar file is in the same directory as the `logstash.conf` file, I tries changing the path, to the one corresponding to the volume of `logstash`. but it didn't work

Comment: @James adding the absolute path doesn't help.

Comment: The problem is only with your path of library there are answer i ELK forum, check out.

Comment: I believe connection string should be `jdbc:mysql://db:3306/ecommerce`

Comment: Btw I think you should copy the driver into the image so it can be picked up. So create a Dockerfile for a new image based ondocker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.1.1  :)

Comment: @michalk Thank you, I already did that, in `- ${PWD}/ls_config:/usr/share/logstash/config/` `ls_config` contains the jar file. I tried updating the value of the `jdbc_driver_library` in the conf file but still got the same error

Comment: Can you try copying the jar into the `/opt/` directory in your image?

Comment: Or try to give full path to jar file `/usr/share/logstash/config/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar` in the jdbc_driver_library.

Comment: @MohamedNidabdella if you have the mentioned path as "logstash-7.2.0\logstash-core\lib\jars" place the jar file here and  jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"

Comment: @michalk tried all of those, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I post this in case someone had the same problem as me. I found the solution:
So the first thing is to use `MariaDB` instead of `MySQL`, it seems that there are a lot of bugs for MySQL and logstash. I also created a user instead of connecting as root (this will imply changes to the `logstash.conf` file)
my `docker-compose.yml` target for my `MariaDB` is as the following

```
   db:
    image: mariadb # mysql
    container_name: ph_mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/ph_datalake/data/shopware:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: "toto"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "123456"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ecommerce

   adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Next, copy the `jar` file containing the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` directly where the jars are located in my container. I did that using a volume target on my `docker-compose.yml` file in the logstash target so it becomes:

```
   logstash:
       image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.1.1
       links:
       - elasticsearch
       - db
       volumes:
       - ${PWD}/ls_config/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf
       - ${PWD}/ls_config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
       - ${PWD}/ls_config/mariadb-java-client-2.4.3.jar:/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/mariadb-java-client-2.4.3.jar 
       command: bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jdbc
       command: logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf
       depends_on:
       - elasticsearch
       - db
```

My `logstash.conf` file is also going to change:

- delete the `jdbc_driver_library => "./mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"` from the config file.
- change the user and password to be the same as the ones on the MariaDB instance.

So it looks like this:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_class => 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'
    jdbc_connection_string => 'jdbc:mariadb://db:3306/ecommerce'
    jdbc_user => 'toto'
    jdbc_password => '123456'
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => 'SELECT * from ecommerce.table;'
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
        user => elastic
        password => changeme
        index => "logstash"
   }
}
```

So up to here, my logstash managed to find the class and initiate a Driver instance to connect, but it didn't connect. For some reason the connection was interpreting the address `jdbc:mariadb://db:3306/ecommerce` as the localhost of my logstash meaning that when logstash tries to connect with `toto` it tries to connect to its own IP address.

So the solution to this was to launch only Logstash, and since it depends on db (MariaDB) and elasticsearch it connected 
`$ docker-compose up logstash`

```
logstash_1       | [2019-08-16T11:22:12,572][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (3.050417s) SELECT * from ecommerce.table;
logstash_1       | [2019-08-16T11:23:53,329][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (3.014069s) SELECT * from ecommerce.table;
logstash_1       | [2019-08-16T11:25:35,980][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (4.357945s) SELECT * from ecommerce.table;
logstash_1       | [2019-08-16T11:27:11,420][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (3.188877s) SELECT * from ecommerce.table;
logstash_1       | [2019-08-16T11:28:50,292][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (3.456620s) SELECT * from ecommerce.table;
```